# json to c# deserialization with json.net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json-deserialization

I know there has been countless posts about json deserialization, but I have followed most of the posts answers, and they haven't worked out. I think my main issue is I can't seem to wrap my head around how Json actually is built up structure-wise.

I have following Json string from an API:

```
{
  "totalCount_str": "3",
  "items": [
    {
      "standing": 10,
      "corporation": {
        "name": "borkedLabs",
        "isNPC": false,
        "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/corporations/98046548/",
        "id_str": "98046548",
        "logo": {
          "32x32": {
            "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98046548_32.png"
          },
          "64x64": {
            "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98046548_64.png"
          },
          "128x128": {
            "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98046548_128.png"
          },
          "256x256": {
            "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98046548_256.png"
          }
        },
        "id": 98046548
      },
      "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/94512721/contacts/98046548/",
      "contact": {
        "id_str": "98046548",
        "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/corporations/98046548/",
        "name": "borkedLabs",
        "id": 98046548
      },
      "contactType": "Corporation"
    },
    {
      "standing": 10,
      "character": {
        "name": "xxxx yyyy",
        "corporation": {
          "name": "xxyshs",
          "isNPC": false,
          "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/corporations/98401169/",
          "id_str": "98401169",
          "logo": {
            "32x32": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98401169_32.png"
            },
            "64x64": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98401169_64.png"
            },
            "128x128": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98401169_128.png"
            },
            "256x256": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98401169_256.png"
            }
          },
          "id": 98401169
        },
        "isNPC": false,
        "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/95161569/",
        "capsuleer": {
          "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/95161569/capsuleer/"
        },
        "portrait": {
          "32x32": {
            "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Character/95161569_32.jpg"
          },
          "64x64": {
            "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Character/95161569_64.jpg"
          },
          "128x128": {
            "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Character/95161569_128.jpg"
          },
          "256x256": {
            "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Character/95161569_256.jpg"
          }
        },
        "id": 95161569,
        "id_str": "95161569"
      },
      "contact": {
        "id_str": "95161569",
        "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/95161569/",
        "name": "xxxx yyyy",
        "id": 95161569
      },
      "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/94512769/contacts/95161569/",
      "contactType": "Character",
      "watched": false,
      "blocked": false
    },
    {
      "standing": -10,
      "alliance": {
        "id_str": "99000003",
        "href": "http://crest.regner.dev/alliances/99000003/",
        "id": 99000003,
        "name": "One One Corporation Alliance"
      },
      "href": "http://crest.regner.dev/characters/90000001/contacts/99000003/",
      "contact": {
        "id_str": "99000003",
        "href": "http://crest.regner.dev/alliances/99000003/",
        "name": "One One Corporation Alliance",
        "id": 99000003
      },
      "contactType": "Alliance"
    }
  ],
  "pageCount": 1,
  "pageCount_str": "1",
  "totalCount": 3
}
```

Note that the items array can contain any number of "contacts".

By using http://json2csharp.com/ I have converted it to classes in C# as following:

```
public class Contacts
{
    public string totalCount_str { get; set; }
    public Item[] items { get; set; }
    public int pageCount { get; set; }
    public string pageCount_str { get; set; }
    public int totalCount { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int standing { get; set; }
    public Alliance alliance { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public Contact contact { get; set; }
    public string contactType { get; set; }
    public Character character { get; set; }
    public bool watched { get; set; }
    public bool blocked { get; set; }
}

public class Alliance
{
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Character
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Corporation corporation { get; set; }
    public bool isNPC { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public Capsuleer capsuleer { get; set; }
    public Portrait portrait { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
}

public class Corporation
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isNPC { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public Logo logo { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Logo
{
    public _32X32 _32x32 { get; set; }
    public _64X64 _64x64 { get; set; }
    public _128X128 _128x128 { get; set; }
    public _256X256 _256x256 { get; set; }
}

public class _32X32
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class _64X64
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class _128X128
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class _256X256
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Capsuleer
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Portrait
{
    public _32X32 _32x32 { get; set; }
    public _64X64 _64x64 { get; set; }
    public _128X128 _128x128 { get; set; }
    public _256X256 _256x256 { get; set; }
}
```

And then trying to deserialize it with:

```
List<Contacts> tempList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contacts>>(response.Content);
```

I appreciate any help that could get me on the right tracks. I get an error currently when trying this way:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ContactWatchlister.Models.Contacts]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'totalCount_str', line 1, position 18.
```

I am currently stuck as I don't get why it is having trouble understanding "totalCount_str" into a string.

I have tried to use `[JsonProperty("attribute")]` on all attributes in my classes to model it correct, but same error.

I'm pretty sure I am doing something rather simple, wrong, but I can't wrap my head around it. Hope you can help! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `response.Content` contains the JSON string you described I think the statement should be:

```
var tempList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contacts>(response.Content);
```

Your JSON has the `"totalCount_str"`, `items`, `pageCount`, `pageCount_str` and `totalCount` fields in the outermost "level", so it can only be deserialized into a class that has those properties (or properties with correct `JsonAttribute`s that correspond  to those fieldnames).

The one you tried would work with the following JSON, where the outermost entity is an array:

```
[   {
    "totalCount_str": "3",
    "items": [
      {
        "standing": 10,
        "corporation": {
          "name": "borkedLabs",
          "isNPC": false,
          "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/corporations/98046548/",
          "id_str": "98046548",
          "logo": {
            "32x32": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98046548_32.png"
            },
            "64x64": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98046548_64.png"
            },
            "128x128": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98046548_128.png"
            },
            "256x256": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98046548_256.png"
            }
          },
          "id": 98046548
        },
        "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/94512721/contacts/98046548/",
        "contact": {
          "id_str": "98046548",
          "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/corporations/98046548/",
          "name": "borkedLabs",
          "id": 98046548
        },
        "contactType": "Corporation"
      },
      {
        "standing": 10,
        "character": {
          "name": "xxxx yyyy",
          "corporation": {
            "name": "xxyshs",
            "isNPC": false,
            "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/corporations/98401169/",
            "id_str": "98401169",
            "logo": {
              "32x32": {
                "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98401169_32.png"
              },
              "64x64": {
                "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98401169_64.png"
              },
              "128x128": {
                "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98401169_128.png"
              },
              "256x256": {
                "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98401169_256.png"
              }
            },
            "id": 98401169
          },
          "isNPC": false,
          "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/95161569/",
          "capsuleer": {
            "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/95161569/capsuleer/"
          },
          "portrait": {
            "32x32": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Character/95161569_32.jpg"
            },
            "64x64": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Character/95161569_64.jpg"
            },
            "128x128": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Character/95161569_128.jpg"
            },
            "256x256": {
              "href": "http://imageserver.eveonline.com/Character/95161569_256.jpg"
            }
          },
          "id": 95161569,
          "id_str": "95161569"
        },
        "contact": {
          "id_str": "95161569",
          "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/95161569/",
          "name": "xxxx yyyy",
          "id": 95161569
        },
        "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/characters/94512769/contacts/95161569/",
        "contactType": "Character",
        "watched": false,
        "blocked": false
      },
      {
        "standing": -10,
        "alliance": {
          "id_str": "99000003",
          "href": "http://crest.regner.dev/alliances/99000003/",
          "id": 99000003,
          "name": "One One Corporation Alliance"
        },
        "href": "http://crest.regner.dev/characters/90000001/contacts/99000003/",
        "contact": {
          "id_str": "99000003",
          "href": "http://crest.regner.dev/alliances/99000003/",
          "name": "One One Corporation Alliance",
          "id": 99000003
        },
        "contactType": "Alliance"
      }
    ],
    "pageCount": 1,
    "pageCount_str": "1",
    "totalCount": 3   } ]
```

Comment: Doh... You are absolutly right. After I changed to that, and fixed my ints to doubles. (10.0 can't be an int) It worked perfectly!

Thanks!